# Uncaught SecureElement.innerHTML cannot be used with BODY elements! when using dhtmlxGantt in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

I am trying to use [dhtmlxGantt](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__howtostart_guides.html) inside a Lightning Component.

CMP

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.dhtmlxgantt_css }" />
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.dhtmlxgantt_js}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
    <div aura:id="chart"></div>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.configureGantt(cmp);
    }
})
```

JS Helper

```
({
    configureGantt: function (cmp) {

        let tasks = {
            data: [
                {
                    id: 1, text: "Project #1", start_date: "12-02-2019", duration: 18, order: 10,
                    progress: 0.4, open: true
                }, {
                    id: 2, text: "Task #1", start_date: "13-02-2019", duration: 8, order: 10,
                    progress: 0.6, parent: 1
                }, {
                    id: 3, text: "Task #2", start_date: "14-02-2019", duration: 8, order: 20,
                    progress: 0.6, parent: 1
                }
            ],
            links: [
                { id: 1, source: 1, target: 2, type: "1" },
                { id: 2, source: 2, target: 3, type: "0" },
                { id: 3, source: 3, target: 4, type: "0" },
                { id: 4, source: 2, target: 5, type: "2" },
            ]
        };

        gantt.init("chart");
        gantt.parse(tasks);
    }
})
```

Yet I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SecureElement.innerHTML cannot be used with BODY elements!

I suspect this is caused by LockerService?

And there is no way around it?

Comment: any library that interacts with your component's DOM is subject to Locker service limitations and has limited support. The version of the library should also be taken into considerations - [Which external Javascript libraries work with Lightning Locker Service?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162225/which-external-javascript-libraries-work-with-lightning-locker-service/162226#162226)

Answer (score 3):

Robs, there are two issues here:

1. **dhtmlxGantt** needs a selector, otherwise it falls back to `<body>`, as we can see in the source code:

```
  toNode: function(t) {
    return "string" == typeof t ? document.getElementById(t) || document.querySelector(t) || document.body : t || document.body
  },
```

In your case, you need to change `<div aura:id="chart"></div>` to `<div id="chart"></div>` because `aura:id` is something you can use in Aura but not outside of it. In your case, because **dhtmlxGantt** can't find the ID, it reverts to `<body>`, something we don't allow for stability and security reasons.

Better, keep `aura:id` and usr to find the element. It's more robust, `aura:id` is private to the component, and you are sure there are no conflicts with something else on the page with `id="chart"`:

```
  gantt.init(cmp.find("chart").getElement());
```

I have tested both, and if I add a little bit of CSS:

```
.THIS {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

2. Now the bad news: **dhtmlxGantt** creates an iframe to detect resize, and that gets things complicated because we don't fully support that in Locker. In my test I had to remove this reference to `contentWindow` from `dhtmlxgantt.js`:

```
,i.contentWindow.addEventListener("resize", ... ),
```

That's not elegant nor supportable long term. We could ask the developer of **dhtmlxGantt** to support an option to inject an alternative resizer.

Your best bet would be to use a Lightning Container Component (LCC). It's the easiest way to get complex code running on the platform.

You can find more about LCC on the [Lightning Container Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm)