# Any formatting JavaScript APIs in LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, formatting

I'd like to format a currency value that a user inputs in a modal dialog as part of a `lightning-datatable` field that is composed of some fixed text and that currency value.

But AFAIK there are no JavaScript APIs in LWC for this kind of thing: it is assumed that such formatting is always part of a template via e.g. [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example) with the results directly output.

Is hand-crafted code or using a 3rd party library and finding ways to hook in the user's locale the only way to go here?

Answer (score 5):

You can access the user's locale via the [i18n](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_i18n) library methods, which you can then pass in to LWC datatable's typeAttributes:

```
import USERLOCALCURRENCY from '@salesforce/i18n/currency';
```

...

```
{ label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', typeAttributes: { currencyCode: USERLOCALECURRENCY }},
```

Comment: Are there any other libraries that are available for us like the `i18n`? Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: @Arthlete That's Salesforce's only offering. It's possible to write a custom cell type + a library like [globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) to provide custom logic, or you can mix-and-match using the two techniques. I'd recommend starting with i18n + the built-in attributes to see if it meets a project's need before going off the beaten path.

Comment: @Arthlete `il8n` is provided by Salesforce so it will likely be the best experience for working with LWCs. There are a number of internationalization JS libraries out there but finding one that plays well with LWCs may be a challenge. There are a handful on the awesome-javascript list. https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript#i18n-and-l10n

Comment: @nbrown Thanks for your input. I'm going to check out that library myself. We don't use i18n in our org, but I'm envisioning a time in the near future where a personal project of mine will need it.

Comment: Thanks all for this input. I'm looking for something quite small to just do data formatting; interesting to see the work going into e,g, pluralisation. Something like https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs may be a better starting pint given that it is broken out into lots of packages.

Comment: Or http://numeraljs.com/. That gets a mention here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162225/which-external-javascript-libraries-work-with-lightning-locker-service.